# How to look for a variable string in libconfig?

Tags: c, libconfig

I'm using `libconfig`.
I've a `.cfg` file. In this file, I have one only category: `Services`. Inside this category, I have many objects. Each object name has this format:

`objectname` + `underscore` + `4numbers`

For example:

```
alfa_1111
```

So, let's consider:

```
Services = 
{

   alfa_1111 = {
     
    key = "value"

  };

   beta_2222 = {
     
    key = "value"

  };

   gamma_3333 = {
     
    key = "value"

  };

}
```

The 4 numbers are a unique identifier. There is one only `1111`, one only `2222` and so on. My scope is to retrivie the key value for a specific object. The problem is, that the only parameter I know, are the 4 numbers.

To be more clear:
I receive for example `2222`. I know that in the file there is one only `2222`, so I look into `beta_2222` and retrieve the key value.

However, I am not aware of the name before the underscore. I simply receive `2222`. So, inside the `.cfg` there could be any name before `_2222` (`x_2222`? `y_2222`? `z_2222`?)

So, in the config lookup I would need something like that:

```
config_setting_t *setting;
config_t cfg;
setting = config_lookup(&cfg, "Services.*_2222);
```

**(with `*` I mean "any character you find until `_2222`")**

Is there a way to say:

**search for the object that contains _2222, it doesn't matter of the previous characters...**

Comment: The C++ classes seems to have functionality to iterate over settings, but there doesn't seem to be any equivalent functions in the C API. Otherwise you could iterate over all settings inside `Service` and just look for a setting ending in the string `"2222"`.

Comment: how could I do this? Do you mean to look for every single object and parse it to verify if it contains _2222?

Comment: If it was possible to get a list of every single "object" then yes that's what I'm proposing. Unfortunately using the public C API it doesn't seem possible to get such a list.